# Indexing a networked Windows drive

Tags: network, finder, spotlight

I'm trying to get my Mac to index a folder on a networked Windows drive. Specifically there is a folder named "FILE SERVER" on that drive that I'm logged in to as owner. It shows up in a Finder window but it is not being indexed.

I tried `mdutil /Volumes/FILE SERVER -i on` but I get the following errors:

`Error: invalid path '/Volumes/FILE'`

`Error: invalid path 'SERVER'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you already try `mdutil /Volumes/FILE\ SERVER -i on` or `mdutil "/Volumes/FILE SERVER" -i` on

Comment: Basically you are not "escaping" the space in the name. And since a space character is a command delimiter in Unix you have to escape it or enclose it in quotes. Klanomath demonstrates the correct command line above.

Comment: I figured I was missing something with the space. Thank you both for that. However, now I'm getting this error: "Indexing and searching disabled."